# Pylons error "No object (name: request) has been registered for this thread" with debug = false

Tags: python, debugging, pylons

I'm unable to access the `request` object in my Pylons 0.9.7 controller when I set `debug = false` in the .ini file. I have the following code:

```
def run_something(self):
    print('!!! request = %r' % request)
    print('!!! request.params = %r' % request.params)
    yield 'Stuff'
```

With debugging enabled this works fine and prints out:

```
!!! request = <Request at 0x9571190 POST http://my_url>
!!! request.params = UnicodeMultiDict([... lots of stuff ...])
```

If I set `debug = false` I get the following:

```
!!! request = <paste.registry.StackedObjectProxy object at 0x4093790>
Error - <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: No object (name: request) has been registered for this thread
```

The stack trace confirms that the error is on the `print('!!! request.params = %r' % request.params)` line.

I'm running it using the Paste server and these two lines are the very first lines in my controller method.

This only occurs if I have `yield` statements in the method (even though the statements aren't reached). I'm guessing Pylons sees that it's a generator method and runs it on some other thread. My questions are:

1. How do I make it work with `debug = false` ?
2. Why does it work with `debug = true` ? Obviously this is quite a dangerous bug, since I normally develop with `debug = true`, so it can go unnoticed during development.

Comment: Maybe debug=false is excluding RegistryManager in middleware.py?

Answer (score 2):

You should not yield from action directly. Try making inner function and returning func():

```
def run_something(self):
    request = pylons.request._current_obj()
    def func():
        print('!!! request = %r' % request)
        print('!!! request.params = %r' % request.params)
        yield 'Stuff'
    return func()
```

Comment: OK, that works. I modified it slightly by assigning `self.request = request._current_obj()`. But why do I have to do this at all and why only with debug = false?

Comment: Because 'request' is a module-level variable of type StackedObjectProxy. It is shared between all threads and performs operations on the real object bound to currently running thread. The reason of getting _current_obj() manually is probably of the Pylons design. I think it 'unbounds' request from the current thread when the action is complete. When pylons yield results from 'func' function the action is already completed.
Not sure about debug=false setting but I suppose it is due to some middleware that changes request behavior.

Comment: You need to set debug=false because in the other case output is buffered and you would not have 'streaming' effect.

Answer (score 0):

When you set up your middleware, enable streaming support in RegistryManager:

```
app = RegistryManager(app, streaming=True)
```

This keeps the registry (aoo_globals etc.) alive until your response has finished iterating.